# Recursively adding files to a Subversion repository

Tags: svn

Is there a way to recursively add all "non added" files to SVN?

I want to do something like

```
svn add trunk/
```

to add all new files, without getting:

```
svn: warning: 'trunk' is already under version control
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to get a list of all files that are not under version control in the directory?

Note that I am only interested in using the command line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the --force option.

Example:

```
svn add * --force
```

Comment: That also fixes a broken svn tree where the directories says it's already added to SVN, but svn status tells a different story.
Thanks for this!

Comment: This also adds everything that you were IGNORING BEFORE. Not cool!

Comment: As CommaToast is mentioning, this ignores the ignores... making it dangerous to use.

Answer (score 10):

You can generate a list of files and add them using xargs

`svn status | awk '/\?/ {print $2}' | xargs svn add`

Answer (score 0):

If the first column of the output from the svn status command is a question mark, then that file is not under version control. See this page on the [svn status command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html) for more information.